# SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: ios, openssl, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

`django-push-notifications` was working with both sandbox and production certificates. But since yesterday it is failing with following errors.

> SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version

No change in our code or our servers. Any ideas, why it has stopped working.

**UPDATE**

OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 
Ubuntu: 14.04

I upgraded to OpenSSL 1.1.1a 20 Nov 2018 but same results.

I also checked TLS version supported by my python using following and got "TLS 1.3".

python -c "import requests; print(requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', verify=False).json()['tls_version'])"

Comment: same happened to us, no resolution yet

Comment: we are also seeing that sometimes connections will succeed and sometimes they will not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an apple server issue. And it has been resolved now. Push notifications are now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Some people upgraded to tls 1.2
Others are working again after doing nothing.
Feels like a problem with certain apple servers.

We added retry logic to our connection code for times when it hit one of these bad apple servers.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114489

several other reports on apple forums
https://forums.developer.apple.com/content?query=push

Answer (score 0):

From a OpenSSL point of view a client SSL Socket connection to a SSL server is failing because none of the SSL/TLS Socket versions supported by the client is enabled (or supported) on the server.

So my guess is that the server has restricted the protocol versions of SSL/TLS it's supports to the point where your openssl client can't handle it any more.  At a guess TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 only now.  Maybe TLS 1.1.

Can you update your client OpenSSL version to a later version to see if it fixes the connection issues?

Also it may help to check (if you can) what protocol versions you are enabling on the client side to make sure all the highest protocol versions are enabled - TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, TLS1.3 - if you have openssl 1.1.1.

Comment: Hi Shane, I updated the original question with more information. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this message coming from (the tls server or the tls client)?  Do you have logs from the other side?  Are you in control of the other side?  Does it happen all the time or just sometimes? If the other side is apple and it only happens sometimes it sounds like a apple server issue where it depends on what apple server you happen it hit.